# Knockout Observable Array of Observable Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, knockout.js

I have passed a model to my View Model from .Net, which is a Object, containing a few fields, and a List, and each of those has another List.

So, an object with a List of Lists.

On my View, I represent this as some data, with a list of Tabs (The first list), and then each tab has a grid of data.

In my Knockout View model, I just have:

```
self.Name = ko.observable("");
self.Width = ko.observable(0);
self.Height = ko.observable(0);

self.TemplateGroups = ko.observableArray();
```

So, my main object, with an observable array (the first list). But, the list within that, isn't observable.

So when rendering my tabls, I do:

```
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="foreach: TemplateGroups">
```

And that renders each tab. And then within each tab, I do this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data.Components">
      <tr  style="cursor: pointer" data-bind="click: $parents[1].ClickedIt">
```

('Components' is the name of the list within the outer list)

Problem is, on my ClickIt function, I am displaying the Idof the row I clicked, and it works. And then I am just trying to change the 'Description' field of this outer list, but ... it's not a function, so, no observed:

```
self.ClickedIt = function () {
    alert(this.Id);
    this.Description("Craig");

}
```

The alert shows the Id, but error on Description("Craig"), as it's not a function.

How can I make the list, within my ObservableArray, observable?

(To be clearer, my model I pass in is an object, which contains a List called TemplateGroups... and then each item in that list, contains a List called 'Components'. It's the Id of one of those Components that I am displaying, but I need to make that list Observable.

Edit: This seems to be what I am looking for (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bZhCk/), but ... I am not defining my array the same way. Instead, they're being passed in from a .Net class (So, converted to JSON, I think). And that .Net class contains a List of another .Net class, which has a List).

Note, My load method:

```
self.loadData = function () {
        $.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            self.Name(data.Description);
            self.Width(data.Width);
            self.Height(data.Height);
            self.TemplateGroups(data.PlateTemplateGroups);
        });
    }
```

Comment: The content of `self.TemplateGroups` are not observable.  They are plain javascript objects.  Perhaps you could use the Mapping Plugin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):  `self.TemplateGroups(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.PlateTemplateGroups));`, in your `self.loadData`.  This way, all properties become observable.

Comment: @JoseLuis - Perfect! Wow, thank you very much! That has worked perfectly. When I want to post my View Model data back to the same structure, is there a way to map the View Model back to the same structure I received it in, with the updated values? So, like a 'toJSON,' or something? also, if you can create an answer, and I can accept it. Thanks! (again!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `self.TemplateGroups` is `data.PlateTemplateGroups`, that is an array and its content are not observable properties (they are javascript objects).

If you want that this objects in this array become observables, you could use the [Mapping Plugin](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
self.loadData = function () {
    $.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
        self.Name(data.Description);
        self.Width(data.Width);
        self.Height(data.Height);
        self.TemplateGroups(
          ko.mapping.fromJS(     //   <--- new
             data.PlateTemplateGrou‌​ps));
    });
}
```

This way, all properties become observables.

If you need to convert this data to a Json format you could use `ko.mapping.toJS()`:

```
ko.mapping.toJS(self.TemplateGroups)
```

Comment: Thanks @JoseLuis - Saving back seem to be an issue though. Is it as simple as just using ko.mapping.toJS(self) to send all the data in the view model, including the List and List of List, back to my WebAPI function, in the same format it was passed to the view model? Or do I need to do a bit more? As I am getting errors when I try the toJS method. It's battling with my clicks/save functions.

Comment: @Craig I don't know, when I send a JSON I do this:  `var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
var unmappedJSON = ko.toJSON(unmapped);` This code goes into a function in my ViewModel, because of this I use `self`.